# El IDE no compila de ninguna manera [Eclipse Juno]

Tags: c++, eclipse

Soy nuevo usándolo. Estaba dispuesto a usarlo para C++. Creé el programa con el Hola mundo para ver que todo funcionara OK, y me decía "Launch Failed. Binary not found" (Antes de compilar, hice Build all).
Busqué en varios post y ninguna opción me sirvió. En este punto, al momento de compilar me dice:

"Launching DEMO Debug has encountered a problem.

A program was not specified in the launch configuration"

Ya no sé que solución más probar, y tengo mucho para hacer con el programa en poco tiempo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Porque no usas Visual Studio para c++? parece que te falta entrar a las propiedades del proyecto y decirle que debe compilar.

Comment: Me especificaron en la materia que tengo que usar si o si este...
¿Cómo haría eso que decís?

Comment: no soy usuario de ese IDE, pero me suena a ser en las propiedades del proyecto. Con boton derecho.

Comment: En "Run/Debug settings" seleccioné el proyecto, y lo edité. El espacio para "C/C++ application" estaba vacío. Ahí le agregué el archivo .cpp.
Cuando lo intento compilar, me dice "Error starting process"

Comment: Fijate en el foro del IDE, ahi deberias tener los pasos para poder instalarlo y. funcione